# Copy varchar into text datatype

Tags: c, oracle

Whats the best way to copy the contents of varchar datatype into text datatype when mixing pro *c and OCI.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sqlda.h>
#include <sqlcpr.h>
#include <sql2oci.h>
#include <sqlca.h>
#include <oci.h>

#define UNAME_LEN 30
#define PWD_LEN 30

varchar username[UNAME_LEN];
varchar password[PWD_LEN];
varchar tnsname[32];

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
if ( argc < 3 ) {
  printf("\nUsage: %s username \n",argv[0]);
  exit(-1);
}

strncpy((char *) username.arr, argv[1], UNAME_LEN);
username.len = (unsigned short) strlen((char *) username.arr);
strncpy((char *) password.arr, argv[2], PWD_LEN);
password.len = (unsigned short) strlen((char *) password.arr);
strncpy((char *)tnsname.arr, argv[3], 20);
tnsname.len = (unsigned short) strlen((char *) tnsname.arr);

text            *uname ;
text            *pwd ;
text            *connstr;
strncpy (uname, username.arr,UNAME_LEN);
strncpy (pwd,   password.arr,PWD_LEN);
strncpy (connstr,tnsname.arr,32);

printf ("username is %s \n",uname);
printf ("password is %s \n",pwd);
printf ("connstr is %s \n",connstr);

return 0;
}
```

I am unable to copy the contents using strncpy.
When i run this the ouput is

```
**username is ger
password is ger
connstr is ger**
```

Whereas i was expecting the output to be scott tiger orcl.

Because i run it with those parameters.

Comment: Did you put the `username` declaration within an `EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION` block? As it is now, you declare an array of `UNAME_LEN` varchar.

Comment: I noticed EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION is not required as it works without that..problem is when trying to copy Username into uname

Comment: then you have to give more detail about your problem... Runtime crash? Compiler error? Linker error? Please edit your question to add as much detail as you can.

Comment: Joachim i have updated my post so it makes more sense and easy for someone to understand my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with OCI for some time, but as I recollect the `text *` type is just a normal character pointer. This means that you try to copy some text into pointers that have not been initialized.

Right now you are writing into the memory pointed to by `uname`, `pwd` and `connstr` without allocating memory for them. This overwrites whatever memory was there to start with, and is undefined behavior.

Either you just want to use the pointers, in which case you make them point to the corresponding array, or you declare them as arrays and copy into them.

The first solution:

```
text            *uname   = (text *) username.arr;
text            *pwd     = (text *) password.arr;
text            *connstr = (text *) tnsname.arr;

printf ("username is %s \n",uname);
printf ("password is %s \n",pwd);
printf ("connstr is %s \n",connstr);
```

The second solution:

```
text            uname[UNAME_LEN];
text            pwd[PWD_LEN];
text            connstr[32];
strncpy (uname, username.arr,UNAME_LEN);
strncpy (pwd,   password.arr,PWD_LEN);
strncpy (connstr,tnsname.arr,32);

printf ("username is %s \n",uname);
printf ("password is %s \n",pwd);
printf ("connstr is %s \n",connstr);
```

For the second solution, you can keep the `text` variables as pointers, and use `malloc` to allocate memory for them, but then you have to `free` that memory when you are done with it.

I would also like to raise an issue with your use of `strncpy`. If the source strings are longer than the length you copy (i.e. `strlen(username.arr) > UNAME_LEN`), then the destination string will **not** be terminated. You might need to do something like this:

```
strncpy (uname, username.arr, UNAME_LEN);
uname[UNAME_LEN - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Joachim Thanks a ton i have gone with your first solution as i prefer it as i need to use character pointers.